# Java Unable To Acquire Thread Lock

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm testing some java multithreading things, and I ran into this problem : 
I have a Thread that calls a method of Producer class and that method has a synchronized block locked on the object I passed in the constructor.
App.class :

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object lock = new Object();
        Producer producer = new Producer(lock);

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                producer.produce();
            }
        });

        producerThread.start();
        try {
            producerThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Producer class :

```
public class Producer {

    private final Object lock;

    public Producer(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void produce() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            System.out.println("Producer started ...");
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer resumed");
        }
    }
}
```

And I get :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:328)
    at Producer.produce(Producer.java:13)
    at App$1.run(App.java:15)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, what happens when I pass a lock object through the constructor, and why its not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you call `wait()` not on `lock` object, but on `this`, while synchronizing on `lock`. Since you do not own monitor on `this`, `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.
So the fix is `lock.wait()`

But even with that fix your code will hang forever, because `notify`/`notifyAll` is never called.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. So, it means to stop the thread that currently has a lock I heve to call wait method of that lock. And notify will be called from another class, which uses the same lock object.